# Confluent 3.3.0 can't change default log directory location

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I've used confluent Kafka before and normally i'd change the `log.dirs=my-NEW-Location` in server.properties file located in `/etc/kafka/`.

I Just installed Confluent 3.3.0 on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.. its starts no problem using command `confluent start kafka`. I've tried to change the `log.dirs` in `server.properties` to my new location but confluent is not picking it up for some reason. After checking the `server.log` file Confluent creates the logs in `/tmp/confluent.SOME_RAMDOM_STRING/`, Is there a way to change this?

G

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's currently a feature of Confluent CLI. It will locate all the data and metadata of the services you are starting under a common location. You may find out which this specific location is any time by running:

```
confluent current
```

By default, Confluent CLI will pick a location under your `${TMPDIR}`, and it will create there a directory with the format you noticed having a random suffix (*confluent.<8 random chars>*). The way to set a path of your choice for this common location when using Confluent CLI is to set the environment variable `CONFLUENT_CURRENT`. For instance:

```
$ export CONFLUENT_CURRENT="/var/confluent"
$ confluent current
/var/confluent.wDDFGXiZ
```

In the above example, assuming that `/var/confluent` exists already, all the data and metadata for the *kafka* service will be located under: `/var/confluent.wDDFGXiZ/kafka`

Let me note that, currently, using Confluent CLI is intended for development only. It's also open source and you may find it's code here: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-cli

Comment: thats what I was looking for, works. Thanks for the quick response and link, hope this help someone else. Hope this helps others...

Comment: for checking in local use command `confluent local current` after setting the variable CONFLUENT_CURRENT. version v1.37.1